# pushy and spany mess up layout

Tags: java, miglayout

### Why does the Label which spans two rows vertically exceed its cell borders?

Compilable code:

```
public class MigLayoutTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 2, debug, fill", "", ""));

        JPanel greyPanel = new JPanel();
        greyPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("<html>text<br>over<br>two<br>rows</html>"), "spany 2");
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("First row"), "");
        mainPanel.add(new JLabel("Second row"), "");
        mainPanel.add(greyPanel, "spanx 2, pushy, grow");


        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

---

Here is a picture:

[image: Label exceeds its borders]

---

I know that I could use the row constraints and set the first two rows not growing and the thrid row to grow. Following exchanged code lines work and do what I want, **but** I don't know how many rows there will be because they are created dynamically.

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 2, debug, fill", "", "[][][fill, grow]"));
(...)
mainPanel.add(greyPanel, "spanx 2, grow");
```

Furthermore if I don't let the first label span two rows, pushy works.
Analogous problem with spanx/pushx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug and has already been reported to MigLayout.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it must be a bug with MigLayout's handling of the cell size. One thing you could do is to put the labels in a separate panel:

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("debug"));

JPanel greyPanel = new JPanel();
greyPanel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("ins 0, debug"));
labelPanel.add(new JLabel("<html>text<br>over<br>two<br>rows</html>"),
                          "pushx, spany");
labelPanel.add(new JLabel("First row"), "pushx, span");
labelPanel.add(new JLabel("Second row"), "pushx, span");
mainPanel.add(labelPanel, "pushx, growx, span");
mainPanel.add(greyPanel, "span, push, grow");
```

This looks the same as your solution with the row constraints and should be usable with adding additional rows of components by adding more panels.

Comment: Yes it is a bug. I reported it some days ago.